# Find a substring that contains increased 1s

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a string only made by `0` and `1`, and I need to find a sub string that starts with one `1`, and ends with another cascade of `1`s, each match of `1` the consecutive `1` increases by one.

For example, `0101101011101` would catch **1**0**11**010**111**.

I tried

```
(?:(1(?(1)\1)).*?)+
```

but [it doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/wc89fp/1/).

| input | groups | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `01` | `0[(1)]` | `1` |
| `1001111` | `[(1)00(11)]11` | `10011` |
| `010011111` | `0[(1)00(11)(111)]` | `10011111` |
| `0100111110001110` | `0[(1)00(11)(111)]0001110` | `10011111` |
| `0100111011001110` | `0[(1)00(11)101100(111)]0` | `10011101100111` |
| `0100111110011110` | `0[(1)00(11)(111)00(1111)]0` | `10011111001111` |

Comment: I don't think you can write that as a regular expression. However, it should be nothing more than a linear scan of the entire string to find all those groups. You want to match as soon as possible to leave as many potential candidates following, so it should probably just be about finding the 1's and counting them, group by group.

Comment: Do you need to do this using only regex?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Preferably regex but it doesn't have to. I'm using PHP7.3 btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also use (with credits to [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv))

```
^0*\K(?:[01]*?((?(1)\1)1))+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `0*` Match optional zeroes
- `\K` Clean the current match buffer
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `[01]*?` Match optional `0` or `1` as least as possible
  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `(?(1)\1)1` If clause, if where is group 1, match what we already have and add a `1`
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ynoHx/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/7mFA8)

```
$strings = [
    "01",
    "1001111",
    "010011111",
    "0100111110001110",
    "0100111011001110",
    "0100111110011110",
    "0100111111111111110001110",
    "0100111011001110",
    "1011010111",
    "0100111011001110",
];

$pattern = '/^0*\K(?:[01]*?((?(1)\1)1))+/m';

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $s, $match)) {
        echo "$s --> " . $match[0] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
01 --> 1
1001111 --> 10011
010011111 --> 10011111
0100111110001110 --> 10011111
0100111011001110 --> 10011101100111
0100111110011110 --> 10011111001111
0100111111111111110001110 --> 10011111111111111
0100111011001110 --> 10011101100111
1011010111 --> 1011010111
0100111011001110 --> 10011101100111
```

Comment: Nice, but would it work with something like `0101101011101`, the very 1st example in the OP? Maybe `^0*((?:[01]*?((?(2)\2)1))+)` is better?

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it fails `0100111011001110`, it gives me `10011` instead of `10011101100111` :/

Comment: Ah I see the example string `1011010111` I thought it should be incrementing per step, let me try to update it.

Comment: @JvdV Yes I think you can dot that, so the last range of 1's should be equal or greater than the largest already `^0*\K(?:[01]*?((?(1)\1)1))+` https://regex101.com/r/3PWwag/1

Comment: This is quite clever, hiroshi's answer works too but ++kodus for detailed explaination

Comment: This is really awesome regex

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
^.*?\K(?:((?(1)\1)1).*?)*(?1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/dam2qA/1/

Comment: Nice, could you add some detailed explaination on *why* this works?

Comment: `^0*\K(?:(1(?(1)\1)).*?)*(?1)` might be a bit more efficient

Answer (score 1):

This uses a combination of regex and a loop.  The regex just looks for the current number of 1's expected and captures the position of the first one (using `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`).  This uses a counter and builds the regex using `/([1]{".$i.",".$i."})/`.  So this will look like `/([1]{1,1})/` etc.

Then in the loop, it increments the number of 1's expected and starts the next search from the position of the last one (offset by the number of 1's found).

```
$results = [];
$offset = 0;
$i = 1;
while ( preg_match("/([1]{".$i.",".$i."})/", $test, $matches,
             PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset  ))   {
    $offset = $matches[1][1] + $i;
    $results[] = $matches[1];
    $i++;
}
print_r($results);
```